# What is the English equivalent for "向...交代“ (meaning how am I supposed to face someone if I fail to keep the promise I made)?

Tags: idioms, translation, chinese

This is usually used in family-related settings. The audience is usually some family member of the person with whom you made a promise. I'll give you a typical example.

Tom is dying, so he asks his friend Jerry to help take care of his son John after he dies. Jerry agrees and tries his best to play the role of a father. However, John keeps acting up and even becomes addicted to drugs since his father's death. Frustrated by John's behavior, Jerry says to John: "How am I supposed to 向 your father 交代? I made a promise to him to take care of you."

In this example, Jerry is implying that he couldn't even face Tom in the afterworld (if it exists). What do people in English-speaking countries usually say in such situations. My question is not necessarily a translation question. I just want to know the English equivalent(s) for these expressions.

Comment: I don't think there's a prominent concept in western Christian thought of having to meet up with ancestors or dead relatives and justify our actions to them (part of the whole "forgiveness for our sins" idea). You might say something like "If your father was still alive, he'd be upset/mad/disappointed..."

Answer (score 2):

**How am I supposed to look [person] in the eye?**

In this example: "How am I supposed to look your father in the eye?"

**From thefreedictionary.com**

> [look (one) in the eye(s)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+them+in+the+eye)
>
> To make eye contact with one, typically in a way that is confident or
> without shame.

This is a slightly broader idiom than what you are requesting.  It can refer to more than just keeping promises.  However the usage: "How can I look your father in the eye" is the closest stock expression we have for what you are asking.

Comment: I would say could since the father is dead in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

We might say something like:

> **How am I supposed to honor my promise to your father?**
>
> **How am I supposed to honor your father's memory?**
>
> **How am I supposed to honor your father's last/final wishes?**

Of course it isn't the same as meeting the father in an afterlife, but *honor* and *memory/promise* make a connection.

Answer (score 0):

There are related idioms, but with significant differences due to fundamental differences in family and societal cultures. (Disclaimer: I don't have expert knowledge about Asian cultures, just inferring from the question.)

In your example, Jerry holds a position of delegated responsibility in which he describes himself as personally responsible for John's wrongdoings. Western culture is so centered around personal culpability that this viewpoint, while possible, is less likely. So instead Jerry might use a number of idioms that put John back under the responsibility of Tom:

> "What would your poor father say if he could see you now?"

> "Your father would be spinning in his grave" (general way of indicating that the deceased would be displeased with something in the present)